# It looks like I'm not getting a straight line when I split a semicircle into four parts using radians

Tags: javascript, math, canvas, angle

Concerns to be addressed:

- looks like the straight line on the left is higher than the one on the right. I don't want that. Why is that happening and how could I fix it?
- Are all the lines(recs) the same length. not sure but it looks like the ones that go outwards at 0.7853981633974483 radians are smaller

```js
window.onload = function(){
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  context.translate(200,200);
  for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    context.save()
    context.rotate(Math.PI / 4 * i);
    context.fillStyle = "red";
    context.fillRect(0,0,70,3 )
    context.restore()

  }
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

EDIT: Also I want to ask you how you would go about labeling these slices that make up the angle. for example slice 1 gets "1" and so on 1 2 3 4 5. it should be positioned by the vertex(angle)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, the lengths are all the same. If the appear different it is likely due to an illusion from the slight overlapping at the origin.

Now the reason why things aren't lining up is due to the nature of rotation and rectangles. When you rotate a `rect` the rotational origin is at the top left corner of the rectangle. So when rotated `180` degrees, the origin of the rectangle will be the bottom right. This can be seen more obviously if you widen your rectangles, and change their colours. For example:

```js
var cols = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow', 'purple'];

window.onload = function(){
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    context.translate(200,200);
    for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        context.save();
        context.rotate(Math.PI / 4 * i);
        context.fillStyle = cols[i];
        context.fillRect(0,0,70,30);
        context.restore();
    }
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

---

Sow how do you fix this? One way to fix is to translate each rect on the y axis, half of its width after rotation. For example:

```js
var cols = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'black', 'purple'];
// the line width (technically rect height)
var width = 3; 
var length = 70;

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
context.translate(200,200);
for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    var rotAmount = Math.PI / 4 * i;    
    context.save();
    context.rotate(rotAmount);
    context.translate(0, -(width / 2));
    context.fillStyle = cols[i];
    context.fillRect(0,0,length,width);
    context.translate(length + 20, 0);
    context.rotate(-rotAmount);
    context.font="18px Verdana";
    context.fillText(i+1,-5,5);
    context.restore();
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

*Also added* `fillText` *as per @markE's comment, to get you started with drawing the numbers.*

So how does this work? Basically after drawing the line, you move the axis to where you want each number to be (`translate`), and then rotate the axis in reverse, the same amount that you originally rotated the line (`rotate`). This will rotate the numbers to their original coordinate system.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I would really appreciate it if you make the numbers between the angles like so people will know which slice is which. right now it's on the line.  There are 4 slice so it should be 1,2,3,4 not 0,1,2,3,4. and the Numbers should be positioned in the middle of the slice. I will accept this answer because I will be very satisfied. The thing is I'm just getting used to positioning and don't know how to do it inside this for loop.

Comment: I almost got it but the numbers are rotating. The numbers should be vertical to the page.

Comment: **... Adding to Matt's good answer:** After `context.restore` (1) rotate to the middle of the current slice `.rotate((Math.PI/4)*i-Math.PI/8)`, (2) translate horizontally outward from the center by about 45 pixels `translate(45,0)`, (3) Now the tricky part, *unrotate* by the amount you've rotated so the number will be upright again `rotate(-((Math.PI/4)*i-Math.PI/8))`, (4) draw the number `if(i>0){context.fillText(i,0,0);}`. [Here's a demo](https://jsfiddle.net/hoe69vcx/).

Comment: I have added an updated example, which should suffice.

Comment: Thanks to the both of you :)